# CruiseControl.NET getting error on a build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cruisecontrol.net

Getting the following on any build running on CC.NET V1.6 on a server.
I have made sure the user running the CC.NET Service is a member of the Administrators group on the server....  So why am I getting this error?

```
Error Message: System.ArgumentException: Access to the path is denied.
   at System.IO.FileSystemInfo.set_Attributes(FileAttributes value)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.set_IsReadOnly(Boolean value)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Vsts.MarkAllFilesReadWrite(String path)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Vsts.MarkAllFilesReadWrite(String path)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Vsts.MarkAllFilesReadWrite(String path)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Vsts.DeleteDirectory(String path)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Vsts.GetSource(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.MultiSourceControl.GetSource(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

Comment: This is a problem with accessing the VSTS repository, not accessing local files.

Comment: ok then maybe a better question is, what changed between v1.4 and v1.6 around how the vsts sourcecontrol tags, etc are setup.  This was fine in 1.4  now it's not working and I can't find decent documentation on VSTS integration with CC.NET since the 3rd party dll is no longer needed.

Comment: http://tfsccnetplugin.codeplex.com/discussions/223025?ProjectName=tfsccnetplugin       My problem seems to stem from the face I'm building in a different DOMAIN than the TFS server is in.  Funny how this worked ok in the previous version.

Comment: You should file a bug with CruiseControl.net, this has to new fixed on their side.

Comment: they have a bug on their site saying this was fixed in 1.6. Somehow magically this is working now.   The other thing I face is the <force> tag on the sourcecontrol block.  If it's in the .config file when I start the service it won't start... saying "unused node <force> detected"  if I take it out, start the service and add it back in it works.  I need this tag it seems since the <Cleancopy> true </cleancopy> doesn't work.  Sigh.  This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moving the comments into a proper answer)

DavieDave: they have a [bug report on their site saying this was fixed in 1.6](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1741). Somehow magically this is working now.

Me: [`cleanCopy` not working is also a known bug](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-2037). The "unused node detected" error message should not be ignored - it means you have a typo in your configuration and it just won't work. Your workaround (removing the offending tag, starting the service, adding the tag again) won't work, as when ccnet will fail to validate the configuration it just will ignore it, it won't re-load it. Such errors are easiest to fix using the [CCValidator](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/CCValidator), it is installed along the server executables and can show you how the CruiseControl.Net sees your configuration file after it is parsed.